# Travis character can not start any token - django application

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, django, heroku, travis-ci

I'm trying to integrate Travis CI to my `django` application and connect it with `heorku`, this is not the first time I'm doing this, but this is the first time I'm facing this error and I don't understand why is he complaining about `python` version in `travis.yml` file, note that I'm using spaces in `yml` file, rather then `tabs`.

My `travis.yml` file is:

```
language: python

python:
    - "3.4"

# command to install dependencies
install:
    - pip install -r requirements.txt

# command to tun tests
script: pytest
```

and I'm invoking `travis setup heorku` command from my terminal, which needs to add `heroku` `api` key to my `yml` file, thus result is showing this

```
found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 4 column 1
```

I have tried this command to `travis encrypt $(heroku auth:token) --add deploy.api_key` but the same thing is happening,

The log form Travis is showing this

```
Worker information

hostname: i-14252cec-precise-production-2-worker-org-docker.travisci.net:4291b6eb-e316-4075-a109-f26333325746

version: v2.5.0-8-g19ea9c2 https://github.com/travis-ci/worker/tree/19ea9c20425c78100500c7cc935892b47024922c

instance: 9ea3797:travis:ruby

startup: 504.511181ms

Could not find .travis.yml, using standard configuration.
system_info

Build system information

Build language: ruby

Build group: stable

Build dist: precise

Build id: 181076246

Job id: 181076247

travis-build version: 557e4084f

Build image provisioning date and time

Thu Feb  5 15:09:33 UTC 2015

Operating System Details

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

Release:    12.04

Codename:   precise

Linux Version

3.13.0-29-generic

Cookbooks Version

a68419e https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/tree/a68419e

GCC version

gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO

warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

LLVM version

clang version 3.4 (tags/RELEASE_34/final)

Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

Thread model: posix

Pre-installed Ruby versions

ruby-1.9.3-p551

Pre-installed Node.js versions

v0.10.36

Pre-installed Go versions

1.4.1

Redis version

redis-server 2.8.19

riak version

2.0.2

mMongoDB version

MongoDB 2.4.12

CouchDB version

couchdb 1.6.1

Neo4j version

1.9.4

RabbitMQ Version

3.4.3

ElasticSearch version

1.4.0

Installed Sphinx versions

2.0.10

2.1.9

2.2.6

Default Sphinx version

2.2.6

Installed Firefox version

firefox 31.0esr

PhantomJS version

1.9.8

ant -version

Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 3 2011

mvn -version

Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T17:29:23+00:00)

Maven home: /usr/local/maven

Java version: 1.7.0_76, vendor: Oracle Corporation

Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre

Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968

OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-29-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

fix.CVE-2015-7547

$ export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages.gz is not what the server reported 13782 14904

W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_restricted_binary-i386_Packages.gz is not what the server reported 13751 14885

W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages.gz is not what the server reported 19576 20785

W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_restricted_binary-i386_Packages.gz is not what the server reported 19521 20707

W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-backports_multiverse_source_Sources.gz is not what the server reported 5886 5888

W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_travis-ci_zero-mq_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-amd64_Packages.gz is not what the server reported 832 1195

W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_ubuntugis_ppa_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-amd64_Packages.gz is not what the server reported 33653 36677

W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_ubuntugis_ppa_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages.gz is not what the server reported 33699 36733

Reading package lists...

Building dependency tree...

Reading state information...

The following extra packages will be installed:

  libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6-dev

Suggested packages:

  glibc-doc

The following packages will be upgraded:

  libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev

4 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 266 not upgraded.

Need to get 8,840 kB of archives.

After this operation, 14.3 kB disk space will be freed.

Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libc6-dev amd64 2.15-0ubuntu10.15 [2,943 kB]

Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libc-dev-bin amd64 2.15-0ubuntu10.15 [84.7 kB]

Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libc-bin amd64 2.15-0ubuntu10.15 [1,177 kB]

Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libc6 amd64 2.15-0ubuntu10.15 [4,636 kB]

Fetched 8,840 kB in 0s (36.2 MB/s)

Preconfiguring packages ...

(Reading database ... 71420 files and directories currently installed.)

Preparing to replace libc6-dev 2.15-0ubuntu10.10 (using .../libc6-dev_2.15-0ubuntu10.15_amd64.deb) ...

Unpacking replacement libc6-dev ...

Preparing to replace libc-dev-bin 2.15-0ubuntu10.10 (using .../libc-dev-bin_2.15-0ubuntu10.15_amd64.deb) ...

Unpacking replacement libc-dev-bin ...

Preparing to replace libc-bin 2.15-0ubuntu10.10 (using .../libc-bin_2.15-0ubuntu10.15_amd64.deb) ...

Unpacking replacement libc-bin ...

Processing triggers for man-db ...

Setting up libc-bin (2.15-0ubuntu10.15) ...

(Reading database ... 71419 files and directories currently installed.)

Preparing to replace libc6 2.15-0ubuntu10.10 (using .../libc6_2.15-0ubuntu10.15_amd64.deb) ...

Unpacking replacement libc6 ...

Setting up libc6 (2.15-0ubuntu10.15) ...

Setting up libc-dev-bin (2.15-0ubuntu10.15) ...

Setting up libc6-dev (2.15-0ubuntu10.15) ...

Processing triggers for libc-bin ...

ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
git.checkout

0.87s$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master https://github.com/Copser/supervisor.git Copser/supervisor

Cloning into 'Copser/supervisor'...

remote: Counting objects: 935, done.

remote: Compressing objectremote: Compressing objects: 100% (408/408), done.

remote: Total 935 (delta 609), reused 832 (delta 519), pack-reused 0

ReReceiving objects: 100% (935/935), 7.13 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.

Resolving deltas: 100% (609/609), done.

Checking connectivity... done.

$ cd Copser/supervisor

$ git checkout -qf ed7591dc0733f616ded644501ee48ecb90d0da15

This job is running on container-based infrastructure, which does not allow use of 'sudo', setuid and setguid executables.

If you require sudo, add 'sudo: required' to your .travis.yml

See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure/ for details.
rvm

0.13s$ rvm use default

Using /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551

$ ruby --version

ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48407) [x86_64-linux]

$ rvm --version

rvm 1.26.10 (latest-minor) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

$ bundle --version

Bundler version 1.7.6

$ gem --version

2.4.5

0.12s$ rake

rake aborted!

No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)

/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'

/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

The command "rake" exited with 1.

Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

Can any one explain me what is going on and how can I over come this?

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong about `yaml` configuration and when I said

> note that I'm using spaces in yml file, rather then tabs.

I was wrong again, I was using `tabs`, ultimately I've solved it with [Travis WebLint](http://lint.travis-ci.org/), I just validated my `yaml` file and saw that I was blind, so validation, it helps.